# javascript execution after a forced download?

Tags: javascript, php, html, download

Try to make a download page with pure php.
For those people that have javascript enabled, I plan to extend the download page with some feedback.

Have done some protyping...
when the user press on the download button (post) the download starts.
There is no page change and the java scripts are still executable on the download page.

Is this something that could rely on, that the javascript still executes after a forced download?

simple example, test.php:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $content = '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        function tick(){
            count++;
            console.log("tick() " + count);
            setTimeout("tick()", 1000);
        }
        tick();
    </script>
    <form method="post" action="">
        Download file</br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    ';
    echo $content;
} else {
    $file = 'contentFile.zip';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Forced download is implemented in `else` block which doesn't include any javascript calls.

Comment: start the download in an iframe